# Android Image view pixelation

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want to add an `ImageView` in my application that displays a photo that has a round overlay, so that it appears as a circle rather than a square. However, when I apply the circle overlay, the edge of the circle is pixelated. How can I change my code so that the edge of the circle isn't so jagged.

This is an example of my code at present...
[image]

Here is my code...

```
public Bitmap getRoundedShape(Bitmap bitmap) {
    int targetWidth = 100;
    int targetHeight = 100;
    Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth,
            targetHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
    Path path = new Path();
    path.addCircle(((float) targetWidth - 1) / 2,
            ((float) targetHeight - 1) / 2,
            (Math.min(((float) targetWidth),
                    ((float) targetHeight)) / 2),
            Path.Direction.CCW);

    canvas.clipPath(path);
    Bitmap sourceBitmap = bitmap;
    canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap,
            new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(),
                    sourceBitmap.getHeight()),
            new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), null);
    return targetBitmap;
}
```

xml border

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">

<stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#fff" />
<solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
```

Comment: What is your current code? There is many ways of rounding an image.

Comment: @shkschneider this is my code

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code, that works great for me (for `Drawable`s):

```
// From Drawable
final RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(ApplicationHelper.resources(), bitmap);
roundedBitmapDrawable.setCornerRadius(Math.min(roundedBitmapDrawable.getMinimumWidth(), roundedBitmapDrawable.getMinimumHeight()) / 2.0F);
return roundedBitmapDrawable;
```

Here is an old version (for `Bitmap`s):

```
// From Bitmap
final Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
final BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
final Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setShader(shader);
final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(circleBitmap)
canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);
bitmap.recycle();
return circleBitmap;
```

Give it a try ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use one of many available libraries?
Just google circular image view, or round image view and you will find what you need.

I've been using [RoundedImageView](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView). It has all I need. =)

If Apache license is not for you, maybe go for 
[CircularImageView](https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView).

Comment: In CircularImageView 
compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
does not work

Comment: @AhmedMohammed Sorry about that. I never really tested CircularImageView. As I said, I've been using RoundedImageView. But, there is a lot of libraries out there, so pick one that suits you best

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Anti-aliasing when drawing a round shape
add/change your code:

```
Paint paint = new Paint;
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap,
    new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(),
                sourceBitmap.getHeight()),
    new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), paint);
```